# Can't launch Chrome DevTools in iOS simulator

Tags: react-native

Using v8.2 simulator, <kbd>Cmd+D</kbd> always show the following error message

```
[RCTLog][tid:0x7fcc2bf4cb90][RCTRootView.m:68]>WebSocket debugger is not available. Did you forget to include RCTWebSocketExecutor?
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Thank you! This my first time post question. I'll take care next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I found the root cause after I tried many different way to solve this problem.

For using Chrome DevTool to debug, iOS project need to import libraries `RCTWebSocketDebugger.xcodeproj` and `libicucore.dylib`.

In react-native examples, `2048`, `Movies`, `TicTacToe` doesn't import these two libraries. That's why it always show error message "WebSocket debugger is not available. Did you forget to include RCTWebSocketExecutor?" in console.

[image]

1. press `+` > `Add Other...` > `<REACT_NATIVE_ROOT>/Libraries/RCTWebSocketDebugger/RCTWebSocketDebugger.xcodeproj`
2. press `+` > search `RCTWebSocketDebugger.a` > `Add`
3. press `+` > search `libicucore.dylib` > `Add`
4. press <kbd>⌘ + R</kbd> in Xcode to run the project
5. open Chrome URL `http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui`
6. press <kbd>⌘ + D</kbd> in iOS Simulator to enable debugging

Answer (score 0):

Possibly similar to this issue:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/311

And also mentioned here:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/297

Looks like it's probably a poor error message for the fact that React Native is unable to connect to the Chrome Debugger. The first link has a possible fix:

```
In RCTWebSocketExecutor.m:
- (instancetype)init
{
return [self initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/debugger-proxy"]];
}
```

> This prevents remote debugging. If I manually change it to my
>   computer's IP, I am able to debug with the Chrome inspector.

Credit to https://github.com/ckknight if it works :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Those issues are not same as mine. And I have found the root cause :)

Comment: Great! Tick the answer to you own question and then other people will know where to look!